# Apollo cache writeQuery inconsistent format

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client

I'm working with the Apollo client cache and trying to follow [their official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#writequery)
but after I played with it a little I found a weird behavior regarding the query arguments.

In the docs we can see that the **writeQuery** contains *variables* with the `id` prop  to correctly select the appropriated item from the cache regarding this `id` to update it with the new data. It looks clear but when I tried to change or even remove the *variables* the **writeQuery** continued to work correctly. It looks like the only `id` and `__typename` in the *data* matter because the cache uses them to determine what kind of data it should update.

Here is the code example:

```
client.writeQuery({
        query: gql`
          query WriteTrack($trackId: ID!) {
            track(id: $trackId) {
              id
              title
              author {
                id
                name
                photo
              }
              thumbnail
              description
            },
          }`,
          data: { // Contains the data to write
          track: {
            __typename: 'Track',
            id: 'c_1',
            title: 'Buy grapes ',
            thumbnail: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dety84pbu/image/upload/famous_cats_epuqcr.jpg',
            description: "Be inspired by famous catstronauts",
            author: {
                "__typename": "Author",
                "id": "cat-2",
                "name": "Grumpy Cat UPDATED",
                "photo": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-d34828365da7"
            }
          },
        },
        variables: {
          id: 'c_1' // The id is presented
        }
      })
```

And the second variant with the removed variables at all. Still works!

```
client.writeQuery({
        query: gql`
          query WriteTrack {
            track {
              id
              title
              author {
                id
                name
                photo
              }
              thumbnail
              description
            },
          }`,
          data: { // Contains the data to write
          track: {
            __typename: 'Track',
            id: 'c_1',
            title: 'Buy grapes ',
            thumbnail: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dety84pbu/image/upload/famous_cats_epuqcr.jpg',
            description: "Be inspired by famous catstronauts",
            author: {
                "__typename": "Author",
                "id": "cat-2",
                "name": "Grumpy Cat UPDATED",
                "photo": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-d34828365da7"
            },
          },
         // I removed the variables and it continues to work fine
        }
      })
```

So my question is: is this behavior applicable for all the **writeQuery** use cases and I could omit the *variables* at all or is it works only in my particular use case somehow? 
But why?
 And why is this behavior inconsistent with the official documentation or did I just miss something?

Thanks for any help!